# Host a React.js site inside React Native, and use React Native Webview to show it. Possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am working on an React Native app that contains a view of 3d models. Given the incomplete GL support of React Native, Native methods (eg. react-three/fiber/naitve) are a deadend. However, React.js does support three.js very well. Is it possible to host a React.js application or a HTML page with JavaScript and pass the webpage to React-Three-WebView component for displaying?

For the JS application, my index.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

and App.js:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import Kick from "./UserAvatarAnimation.js";

import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <OrbitControls />
      <ambientLight intensity={0.6} />
      <directionalLight intensity={0.5} />
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Kick />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

For the HTML file method:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-animation-component/dist/aframe-animation-component.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.3.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene
    background="color: #AEC7EB"
    renderer="colorManagement: true; logarithmicDepthBuffer: true;"
    vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" 
    shadow="type: pcfsoft" 
    device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false"
    id="scene">
        <a-entity id="tree" position="0 0 0" animation-mixer="clip: *;" gltf-model="src: url(./userAvatarAnimation.glb);"></a-entity>    

        <a-entity camera look-controls orbit-controls="target: 0 0.8 0; minDistance: 1; maxDistance: 2; initialPosition: 0 5 15"></a-entity>

        <a-asset-item id="tree" animation-mixer="clip: Armature;" src="/** GLTF MODEL URL */"></a-asset-item>

        
</a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [expo-gl](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/gl-view/)? If you tie [expo-three](https://github.com/expo/expo-three) to it says using react-fiber becomes possible

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But the expo-gl crashes upon any complicated model. So probably not my best option.

Comment: You could try creating a html string that you render with a web view. I tried to get it working but gave up [here](https://snack.expo.dev/blh9msJXl)